# Plotting DataFrame columns as Series sets unexpected arguments

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Here is an issue when plotting a dataframe:

The dataframe looks like

```
   i  ii  n  b
0  1   0  3  0
1  4   1  5  0
2  4   0  1  5
3  4   1  2  6
4  6   0  3  0
5  6   1  4  3
```

(code to create below). I'd like to plot stacked bars for same values of `i`, and I want bars to belong to groups according to `ii`. When I select only certain rows of the dataframe, I have issues plotting, forcing me to explicitly convert the dataframe's columns (which are extracted as pandas Series) to lists. (Note that I cannot use `pivot`, as I have multiple rows for some (`i`, `ii`) combinations.)

Why can I not directly pass a Series to `matplotlib.pyplot.bar()` (code for figure 3)?
Why does using Series affect the width of bars, which cannot be overridden by an explicit argument `width`?

Is there a way to produce the desired plot in a better way?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'i':[1,4,4,4,6,6], 'n':[3,5,1,2,3,4]})

df['ii'] = df.index % 2
df2 = df.set_index(['i', 'ii'])
df2["b"] = df2.groupby(level='i')['n'].cumsum() - df2.n
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)

# This produces expected outcome
plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()
ix = df2[df2.ii==0]
plt.bar(x=list(ix.i), height=ix.n, bottom=list(ix.b))
ix = df2[df2.ii==1]
plt.bar(x=list(ix.i), height=ix.n, bottom=list(ix.b))
plt.show()

plt.figure(2)
plt.clf()
ix = df2[df2.ii==0]
plt.bar(x=ix.i, height=ix.n, bottom=list(ix.b))
ix = df2[df2.ii==1]
# The following line will draw a bar with unexpected width of bar
plt.bar(x=ix.i, height=ix.n, bottom=list(ix.b))
plt.show()

plt.figure(3)
plt.clf()
plt.show()
ix = df2[df2.ii==0]
plt.bar(x=ix.i, height=ix.n, bottom=ix.b)
ix = df2[df2.ii==1]
# The following line will fail
plt.bar(x=ix.i, height=ix.n, bottom=ix.b)
# error:
# TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
# apparently matplotlib tries to set line width
```

Desired output: [image: Desired bar plot output]

Comment: This was an issue in matplotlib, which was fixed in version 3.1.2. (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/15166)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you get such kind of error when the function expects a single value instead of that you passed an array. In many cases, we can use np.vectorize to apply a function that accepts a single element to every element in an array. It seems this is not a case here. Why you do not want to pass the list as you did in the first plot?

```
plt.bar(x=list(ix.i), height=list(ix.n), bottom=list(ix.b))
```

Comment: Thanks- because I’d like to understand the behaviour. It does not seem consistent (after all, it works without conversion to list in the first call, and I can’t detect the fundamental difference between the input data). If it’s a bug in matplotlib(?) I’d like to file it as such. If there is a better way of doing this without conversion, perhaps with some operation on the original dataframe, I’d like to do it that way.

Comment: Sounds good. Please keep us updated if you find any reason behind this.